# add a computed column in sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a situation where I have two tables and I want to have a computed column.

Table 1: `VacationMaster`

```
PrefVacationId     |      Description
-----------------------------------------------
1                  |        abc
2                  |        xyz
3                  |        lmn
4                  |        pqr
5                  |        wqa
```

Table 2: `VacationMapping`

```
PrefVacationId [fk]    |      UseID  |   ID (PK of this table) 
-----------------------------------------------
    1                  |        1    |    1
    4                  |        1    |    2
    5                  |        1    |    3
    1                  |        2    |    4
    2                  |        3    |    5
```

What I need is every time all the list vacation available will be coming from master table
for every user. I will be supplying `userid` as an input to my procedure and the result should look like this.

For `userID = 1` as input

```
PrefVacationId     |      Description  |       IsSelected(Computed column)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1                  |        abc        |        true        
2                  |        xyz        |        false
3                  |        lmn        |        false
4                  |        pqr        |        true
5                  |        wqa        |        true
```

Hope I am making some sense, how to make this query.

Comment: Why is this tagged C#? I'm not sure how it's relevant where you're consuming this query. All tagging it as C# does is make it so that code samples are syntax highlighted for C# instead of SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```sql
Select 
   vm.PrefVacationId,
   Description,
   CASE WHEN vMap.PrefVacationId IS NOT NULL THEN 'True'
   ELSE 'False'
   END IsSelected
From VacationMaster vm
Left Outer Join VacationMapping vMap
ON vm.PrefVacationId = vMap.PrefVacationId 
AND vMap.UserID = @UserID
```